# cxgrid multiple row-column

Tags: tcxgrid

How to output a "multiple row-column" (don't know if the term is correct) in cxgrid? the output should be like this:

```
Header 1         Header 3           Header 5

Header 2         Header 4           Header 6

----

Data 1.1         Data 1.3           Data 1.5

Data 1.2         Data 1.4           Data 1.6

Data 2.1         Data 2.3           Data 2.5

Data 2.2         Data 2.4           Data 2.6
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to do this. Using `TcxDBBandedTableView` you can place columns in multiple rows.
In order to accomplish this delete it's default tableview and add TcxDBBandedTableView, then bind it to a datasource and change columns positions (by dragging it) by testing it yourself.